# SingleOrDefault() seems to be throwing a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The documentation for `SingleOrDefault()` indicates that it can return one of two exceptions :

```
Exception                     Condition
ArgumentNullException         source is null.  
InvalidOperationException     The input sequence contains more than one element.
```

With that in mind, how in the world is the code below returning a `NullReferenceException`?

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
public Domain.Data.ServiceJob SelectByServiceJobID(int serviceJobID)
{
    using (_dataContext = new ServiceJobDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().WriteOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            Domain.Data.ServiceJob result = new Domain.Data.ServiceJob();

            Mapper.CreateMap<LINQ.ServiceJob, Domain.Data.ServiceJob>();

            //THIS STATEMENT BELOW HAS TO BE THROWING A NullReferenceException
            ServiceJob linqList = _dataContext.ServiceJobs.Where(p => p.ServiceJobID == serviceJobID).SingleOrDefault();  

            //Broke the above statement up to debug sporadic exception here - linqList should never be null
            if(linqList!=null)                    
                result=Mapper.Map<ServiceJob, Domain.Data.ServiceJob>(linqList);

            return result;

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Added this to catch the sporadic phantom error
            throw new Exception(String.Format("SelectByServiceJobID({0}) ERROR : {1}",serviceJobID,e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my stack trace.

```
xxxxx.Services.ServiceAgent.DoWork - System.Exception: SelectByServiceJobID(22) ERROR : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at xxxxx.Resources.Data.LINQ.ServiceJobService.SelectByServiceJobID(Int32 serviceJobID)
   at xxxxx.Resources.Data.LINQ.ServiceJobService.SelectByServiceJobID(Int32 serviceJobID)
   at xxxxx.Controllers.Data.ServiceJobController.SelectByServiceJobID(Int32 serviceJobID)
   at xxxxx.Services.ServiceAgent.xxxxxServiceAgent.DoWork()
```

Here is how that data call is being accessed in the service code.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    ....  
    ServiceJob serviceJob=new ServiceJobController().SelectByServiceJobID(thisServiceJob.ServiceJobID);
    if (serviceJob.ServiceJobStatusID  != (int)ServiceJobStatusEnum.Stopped)
    {                                
        //Time to do some work
        _ThreadPool.AddWorkItem(new ThreadPoolWorkItem(thisServiceJob.ServiceJobID, true, true, 1, new SJDelegate(doWorkForServiceJob),thisServiceJob));
    }
    else
    {
        //set status to stopped                              
        thisServiceJob.ServiceJobStatusID = serviceJob.ServiceJobStatusID;                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if `_dataContext` is null?

Comment: When you debug, is `_dataContext` null? Is `_dataContext.ServiceJobs` null? Create the Linq query without the selector at the end and see what it returns (you can do this in the debugger as well). Do you have a null `ServiceJob` in the `ServiceJobs`?

Comment: How could _dataContext be null? This is called in a windows service every ten seconds and will blow up catch an exception every two days or so, recover and everything is fine.

Comment: Neither `_dataContext` nor `_dataContext.ServiceJobs` could be `null` or the stack trace wouldn't show calling the `SingleOrDefault` method. The call stack is deep enough that it's actually getting into `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: The SingleOrDefault is where the exception is coming from, however, I have yet to determine why the stack trace contains 2 entries for --> xxxxx.Resources.Data.LINQ.ServiceJobService.SelectByServiceJobID(Int32 serviceJobID)

Comment: As an aside, you're handling the exception incorrectly. You should use the overload on the Exception constructor that allows you to pass the originating exception as an inner exception rather than stringifying the original exception into the message.

Comment: Craig W. I am just setting up a quickish trace for this single purpose. Thanks for the input. I get what you are saying.

Comment: I've looked at the stack trace more closely and see you actually have two methods with the name `SelectByServiceJobID`. One is `Controllers.Data.ServiceJobController.SelectByServiceJobID` and other is `Resources.Data.LINQ.ServiceJobService.SelectByServiceJobID`. From the stack trace it appears the first one calls the second one and the second one calls itself recursively. Are you sure this is the code for the one that is actually throwing the exception? Also, can you do a debug build so you can get line numbers on the stack trace?

Comment: Yea, it looks like it is calling itself recursively, however, I have triple checked - that is not the case :(

Comment: Have you debugged `DoWork` to see what is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by trial and error. FOR SOME REASON, having a private class scoped variable _dataContext and function scoped variable with the same name was causing the issue. When I removed the class scoped variable _dataContext from all the repository classes, these errors stopped. 0_o

```
public class myClass
{
    private _dataContext =new ServiceJobDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().WriteOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString);

    public Domain.Data.ServiceJob SelectByServiceJobID(int serviceJobID)
    {
        using (_dataContext = new ServiceJobDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().WriteOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString))
        {
         //...
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used similar architecture to Declare and/or instantiate a Context with various types of Access Modifiers and have found that It is more trouble than its worth. I Understand the Tendency to encapsulate the process but ultimately the straightforward
using (ContextObject Context = new ContextObject()) {.......
is more transparent and seems to cause less headaches

Comment: You did not have two variables `_dataContext`, you only had the field (class-level variable). There was no local (method-level) variable by that name. This could have been a problem if the field `_dataContext` was accessed by two methods (or by two invocations of one method) at the same time. In your case the method calls itself, so the same field is used by several "versions" of the method which explains the issue.

Comment: You are correct, it was not a local variable. I was "re-upping" the class scoped variable. You could be shining light on it in a way I have not thought about.

Comment: Exactly. If you had been `using (var _dataContext =` instead, then it would be a new local variable on each "recursion" which would have worked. It is dangerous to say `using (alreadyExisting =`, and always better to __declare__ a variable in there, and its scope will be limited to the `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

you are right with the docu. I quickly looked up the definition for **ArgumentNullException**:

*Remarks*

*An ArgumentNullException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the **passed arguments** is null but should never be null.*
[msdn docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

You don't pass a argument. But the object you calling the method on is in one of your iterations is null. *(_dataContext.ServiceJobs doesn't contain a service job ID 22)*

Validate if that part   `_dataContext.ServiceJobs.Where(p => p.ServiceJobID == serviceJobID)` isn't null before calling `.SingleOrDefault();`

Best regards,
Butti

Comment: The OP is not getting an `ArgumentNullException`, but a `NullReferenceException`.  That's the point of the question.

Comment: Correct, he was asking why he got a null reference exception and not one of the listed exceptions. I explained why a ArgumentNullException isn't valid in that context and pointed out, that for his JobID 22 he caught a nullReferenceException in his where claus. Furthermore I mentioned the part of code where he need to do a null validation.

Comment: If you call `SingleOrDefault` on a `null` `IEnumerable`, or in the case `IQueryable`  you should get an `ArgumentNullException` because `SingleOrDefault` is an extension method and the object you call it on is actually an argument passed into the method via syntactic sugar.  Basically I'm saying that `_dataContext.ServiceJobs.Where(p => p.ServiceJobID == serviceJobID)` isn't `null` and shouldn't be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A NullReferenceException can be thrown any time "there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference" (according to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.nullreferenceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This means any code that tries to call a method or property on a null object will trow this execption.

I suspect your LINQ query (`Where()`) is returning null.

Comment: Why would the `Where()` clause be null instead of returning an empty collection? And anyways, `SingleOrDefault` will throw an ArgumentNullException if the source is null, not an NRE. Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: SingleOrDefault needs a non-null reference first in order to throw anything. There is obviously a null object being referenced in that line of code. The OP should break it down to smaller pieces to see which object is null.

Comment: No, it does not need a non-null reference first to enter the SingleOrDefault body. It's an extension method. The result of the where clause is not having `SingleOrDefault` called on it, it just looks that way. The result of the where clause ends up as a parameter to SingleOrDefault. It's the same as this: `SingleOrDefault(_dataContext.ServiceJobs.Where(p => p.ServiceJobID == serviceJobID));` The documentation clearly states if the source parameter is null (in this case, the result of the where clause), then it will throw an ArgumentNullException, not an NRE. Your answer is wrong.